# get first 2 characters of each index in array in python

Tags: python, string, numpy, indexing

[image]

I am trying to access the first two letters of each index in a numpy array in python:
I have read previous forum of the error "'int' object is not subscriptable , I know it;s not a string, but for my work it's better to be numpy.array or if anyone suggest me with another thing, please help,

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import os
import os.path
with open('trial.dat', 'r') as f:
     data = f.readlines()
     data = [(d+' ')[:d.find('#')].rstrip() for d in data]

x=len(data[0])
x_1=eval(data[0])
y=np.concatenate(x_1)
print(type(y))
for i in range (x):
    if y[i[:2]]=='IS': # expected to be IS andso on.depened on the index
         print('ok-CHOICE ONE ')
elif y[i[:2]]=='AT':  
     print('NOTok ')
else:
     print()
```

Data to be used in the .dat file:

```
[["IS-2","AT-3","IS-4"]]                # TYPE OF GN
```

Comment: Please include a sample of `data` and your expected output.

Comment: @not_speshal
Just added a picture of the data file,

Comment: @not_speshal Ok, sorry i tried to attach it, but could not,

Comment: Is your file just one line?

Comment: Side note:  `eval` is very dangerous, but your data looks like valid JSON (when the comment is removed).  You could use `json.loads` instead.

Comment: @not_speshal  yes, I just tried to modify the file just to present the problem in a simple way

Comment: @TimRoberts   May I ask why eval is dangerous ? and what is the difference when I use json.loads or readlines ??

Comment: Because `eval` executes arbitrary Python code.  A hacker could replace your file with "os.system('rm -rf /')" and crash your system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't efficiently slice string elements with `[:2]`, but you can use `astype` to truncate the strings:

```
In [306]: alist = ["IS-2","AT-3","IS-4"]
In [307]: np.array(alist)
Out[307]: array(['IS-2', 'AT-3', 'IS-4'], dtype='<U4')

In [309]: np.array(alist).astype('U2')
Out[309]: array(['IS', 'AT', 'IS'], dtype='<U2')
```

The resulting array could be tested against 'IS' etc:

```
In [310]: np.array(alist).astype('U2')=='IS'
Out[310]: array([ True, False,  True])
In [311]: np.array(alist).astype('U2')=='AT'
Out[311]: array([False,  True, False])
```

Using two `where` steps:

```
In [312]: np.where(Out[309]=='IS', "ok-CHOICE ONE", Out[307])
Out[312]: array(['ok-CHOICE ONE', 'AT-3', 'ok-CHOICE ONE'], dtype='<U13')
In [313]: np.where(Out[309]=='AT', "NOTok", Out[312])
Out[313]: array(['ok-CHOICE ONE', 'NOTok', 'ok-CHOICE ONE'], dtype='<U13')
```

`np.select` could probably used as well.

Comment: Thank you so much, would it be possible also to get the last two characters, (which are numbers (integer in that case ??)

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Consider this as a starting point.  Notice the simple change to handle multiple lines.

```
import json

data = """\
[["IS-2","AT-3","IS-4"]]                    # TYPE OF GN
[["IS-2","AT-3","IS-4"]]                    # TYPE OF GN
[["IS-2","AT-3","IS-4"]]                    # TYPE OF GN
[["IS-2","AT-3","IS-4"]]                    # TYPE OF GN"""

for row in data.splitlines():
    row  = row.partition(' ')[0]
    row = json.loads( row)

    for i in row[0]:
        if i[:2] == "IS":
            print(i,"OK" )
        elif i[:2] == 'AT':
            print(i, "NOT OK")
        else:
            print(i, "unknown")
```

Output:

```
IS-2 OK
AT-3 NOT OK
IS-4 OK
IS-2 OK
AT-3 NOT OK
IS-4 OK
IS-2 OK
AT-3 NOT OK
IS-4 OK
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback, 
mmm... I just would prefer to use numpy as I have a lot of other inputs and need them to be an array ?

Also, in the above mentioned code, i got the following error:
line 4, in <module>
    data = data.partition(' ')[0]
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'partition'

Comment: You have string data.  `numpy` doesn't really help you here.  And clearly, if you are running through a LIST of such lines, then you need an outer loop.  `for row in my_data:` / `for i in row[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
with open('trial.dat') as f:
    line = f.readline() #readline (singular) since the file has only one line
    data = [word.strip('"') for word in line.split("#")[0].strip(" []").split(",")]

for string in data:
    if string.startswith("IS"):
        print(f"{string}: ok-CHOICE ONE")
    elif string.startswith("AT"):
        print(f"{string}: NOT ok")
    else:
        print(f"{string}: Other")
```

###### Output:

```
IS-2: ok-CHOICE ONE
AT-3: NOT ok
IS-4: ok-CHOICE ONE
```

Comment: Can not we do like my earlier code, 
as the file will contain other lines , and do not wanna change read approach ??
Also, I am wondering not other way to read index inside index as I wanna